# Sub Surf looking weird how do I invert the curve direction

Tags: mesh, subdivision-surface

Weird inverted curve from what I want

[image: Weird inverted curve from what I want]

How I want it to curve

[image: How I want it to curve]

Why is my subsurf "cage" curved in the opposite direction of what I want? How can I flip the curve the other way to create the edge of this car window? I want it like the second image!

Comment: Probably have inverted normals (edit mode, select all, shift+n). And (eventually) you should model a loop following the edge.

Comment: Tried that one bro, its not the normals :(

Comment: So... merge by distance... and if not you should updload your file using https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/

Comment: Still didnt work [<img src="https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/embedImage.png?bid=6583" />](https://blend-exchange.giantcowfilms.com/b/6583/) if you could help bro id really appreciate it!

Comment: Are you talking about the pinching part near the back of the car? Screen captures are not showing the same or there are hidden faces, I think

Comment: Im talking about where the window meets the blue body of the car, the body curves away from the window instead of curving around it

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The issue is due to calculated (from subdivision modifier) material assignment which follows edge loops.

You need a loop around the window.

Select the window edges like so:

[image]

Then bevel using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>B</kbd>, with 2 segments:

[image]

That will give this result:

[image]

[image]

Comment: Thank you so much dude, this done it! wasnt aware of this technique !

Answer (score 2):

Merge and weld these four edges.

[image: merge]

To make it completely smooth, you will have to add a supporting edgeloop on the outer side.

[image: merge]

This is the resulting loop.

[image: res]